# problem with python editors, Pycharm, and VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling, pycharm, interpreter

I have a problem with my Python editors, PyCharm and VS Code.
I want to run some code with the speech_recognition package but the output is nothing. I try in both editors and the result is the same. when I run this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
except:
    pass
```

the Output is:

```
"C:\Users\Milad Payandeh\PycharmProjects\romantic alexa\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Milad Payandeh\PycharmProjects\romantic alexa\main.py" 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image: Click to see the output screen]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try *not* handling the exception with `try`/`except`? When you do this, it shows you an error message, right? Did you try *reading* that? Anyway, please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; we are looking for questions to help build a searchable Q&A library - not to get you out of trouble. We [do not care](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) about your deadlines, and will [edit irrelevant bits like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) out of questions.

Comment: Your code fails at `with sr.Microphone() as source` and is being handled at except block with no output

Comment: what is the point of `except: pass`? that's pretty dangerous code and i'd hate to see that be used in a production environment somewhere.. lol.

Comment: do you see the print output in the terminal panel?

Comment: It's not for any product, Just I wanna test and configure it to make a  presentation for the class. It's not working and I don't know how to fix that .